# Does someone see my mistake when calculating inverse of 34 mod 89?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

This is from Discrete Mathematics and its Applications
[image]

I am doing 6b. The method in example 2 is basically using Euclid's Algorithm to make sure that the greatest common divisor is 1 and then back substituting to find Bezout coefficients. Here's my work so far

First Euclid's Algorithm 
89 = 34(2) + 21
34 = 21(1) + 13
21 = 13(1) + 8
13 = 8(1) + 5
8 = 5(1) + 3
5 = 3(1) + 2
3 = 2(1) + 1
2 = 1(2) + 0

Because 1 is the last remainder before it hits 0, it is the gcd, meaning the inverse of 34 modulo 89 exists.

And then back substituting
 
1 = 3 - 1(2)
1 = 3 - 1 (5 - 3(1))
1 = -5 + 2(3)
1 = -5 + 2(8 - 5(1))
1 = 2(8) + (-3)(5)
1 = 2(8) + (-3)(13 - 8(1))
1 = (-3)(13) + (-1)(8)
1 = (-3)(13) + (-1)(21 - 13(1))
1 = (-1)(21) + (-2)(13)
1 = (-1)(21) + (-2)(34 - 21(1))
1 = (-2)(34) + (1)(21)
1 = (-2)(34) + (1)(89 - 34(2))
1 = (-4)(34) + (1)(89)
From here I can see that -4 is the inverse because it is the coefficient of a.
So I represented the inverse in this notation
(-4)(34) $\equiv$ 1 mod(89) 
but -4 * 34 = -136 - 1 = -137 which isn't a multiple of 89.... Does anyone see the issue? Even when I typed this, I didn't see any arithmetic issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is at this position:

> 1 = 2(8) + (-3)(13 - 8(1)) 
>   1 = (-3)(13) + (-1)(8)

Comment: Ahhh nice catch. Thank you :)

Comment: Should i refractor  my question to incorporate this?

Comment: Since $1 = -3 \cdot 13 + 5 \cdot 8$, you have to redo your calculations from that point to find the correct inverse.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Should I leave my question the way it is or fix it and show that I have the correct answer?

Comment: @committedandroider I would leave everything you have already written as is so that users of this site know what prompted your original question.  Once you determine the correct inverse, you can always add an edit to either your question or a comment on aRaRa's answer stating that you found the correct inverse based on what you learned from his/her answer.